# Test Class - Never achieve the overall code coverage and always is 0%

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage, before-trigger

I created a trigger for when an incident has the status changed to Canceled, a calculation is performed. I created the test class, but I never get the code coverage to migrate my trigger to production.

I read several articles, but I can't solve it. Below I am pasting the trigger and then the test class. Can anyone help me understand what I did wrong, or what I didn't do right?

```
trigger Trigger_CalculaBH_Cancelado on BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c (before update) {
    
    for(BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c BMC_inc: Trigger.new){
       
        if(helper.isSupportProfile()) return;
        
        try{
            //seta id layout Banco de Horas
            String BMC_LayoutId = [SELECT Id 
                                   FROM BMCServiceDesk__ConsoleLayoutDetail__c 
                                   WHERE name = 'Requisição - Banco de Horas' limit 1][0].Id;
            
            //verifica condição da requisição Cancelada
            If (BMC_inc.BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c == 'CANCELADO' && BMC_inc.Estimativa_Banco_de_Horas__c <> NULL && BMC_inc.BMCServiceDesk__RF_FKLayout__c == BMC_LayoutId && BMC_inc.CG_BH_CONTABILIZADO__c==FALSE){
                //ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'ENTROU'));
                
                //seta franquia do IC
                Decimal franquiaContrato = [SELECT Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c
                                            FROM BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c
                                            WHERE Id =: BMC_inc.Contrato_de_Banco_de_Horas__c limit 1][0].Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c; //dominio decimal
                
                //seta a Franquia informada
                Decimal franquia = franquiaContrato; //dominio decimal
                
                //seta a estimativa informada
                String estimativa = BMC_inc.Estimativa_Banco_de_Horas__c; //dominio tempo
                
                //separa as partes da string informada (estimativa)
                List<String> estimativaSplit = estimativa.split(':');
                Decimal estimativaDecimal = Decimal.valueOf(estimativaSplit[0])+Decimal.valueOf(estimativaSplit[1])/100;
                
                //Calcula o desconto do Banco de Horas (base 100)
                Decimal resultadoFranquia = (franquia+estimativaDecimal);
                
                BMC_inc.CG_BH_CONTABILIZADO__c=TRUE;
                
                //atualiza registro no cmdb
                List<BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c> recContratoUpdate = [SELECT Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c
                                                                              FROM BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c
                                                                              WHERE Id =: BMC_inc.Contrato_de_Banco_de_Horas__c limit 1];
                
                for (BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c rec : recContratoUpdate) {
                    rec.Franquia_Banco_de_Horas_Variavel__c = resultadoFranquia;
                }
                update recContratoUpdate;
                
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Trigger.new[0].addError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And now the Test.

```
@isTest
public class Test_Trigger_CalculaBH_Cancelado {
    @isTest 
    static void testBH_Cancelado() {

        System.runAs(testHelper.getSupportUser()){
            // Habilita todas as entidades do Change Data Capture para notificações.
            Test.enableChangeDataCapture();
            // Seleciona um registro
            List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c> BMC_Incidente = [SELECT Id, BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c
                                                               FROM BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c
                                                               WHERE ((BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c = 'ABERTO')
                                                                      OR(BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c = 'DESIGNADO')
                                                                      OR (BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c = 'EM ANDAMENTO'))
                                                               AND Estimativa_Banco_de_Horas__c != NULL
                                                               AND BMCServiceDesk__RF_FKLayout__c IN (SELECT Id
                                                                                                      FROM BMCServiceDesk__ConsoleLayoutDetail__c
                                                                                                      WHERE name = 'Requisição - Banco de Horas')
                                                               Limit 1];
            
            // Um registro de teste
            For (BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c BMC_inc : BMC_Incidente){
                // Debug
                System.debug('Incidente: ' + BMC_inc);
                
                // Update
                BMC_inc.BMCServiceDesk__FKStatus__c = 'a4w7X000000Fd21QAC';
                BMC_inc.CG_BH_CONTABILIZADO__c = TRUE;
                Test.startTest();
                update BMC_inc;
                
                // Chama a trigger
                Test.getEventBus().deliver();
                Test.stopTest();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the 0% code coverage when you try to deploy, or is this output elsewhere?  Have you run the tests in either the developer console, CLI or through your IDE and made sure they run and pass?

Comment: Hi, David. I read it before, but does not help me.

Comment: In test class does your list BMC_Incidente returns any rows, if not it will not run, also i cannot see any test setup method where the teat data is being created

Comment: Hi Sumit. the query returned the results I wanted, I improved it now, it keeps bringing results. but I can't seem to achieve anything in code coverage, it always 0%

Comment: And my intention is to execute the test as humans will. Just change the status and run the trigger to make some calcs.